# How to select the value from dropdown box in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below having my code.I need to select the option values like value1,value2..

```
 <td class="column-label" width="50%">
<div id="divRawMaterials" name="Companies" style="position: relative">
 <select name="yieldStandardDTO.rawMaterialName" size="1" onmouseover="dropdowntooltip(this);" onmouseout="return nd();" 
nmousedown="showtooltip(this);" onchange="chooseYieldItems('name');" style="width:205px;" class="select"><option value="">-- Select --</option>

<option value="010080159">value1</option>
<option value="010080024">value2</option>
<option value="010080071">value3</option>
<option value="010030014">value4</option>
<option value="010090009">value5</option>
```

And 
I tried below methods but it doesn't work.Pls help me out of this.

```
  METHOD:1
  Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("yieldStandardDTO.rawMaterialName")));
System.out.println(dropdown);
//dropdown.selectByVisibleText("value1");
//dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
dropdown.selectByValue("value1");

  METHOD:2
 WebElement selectMonth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divRawMaterials']/select"));

List<WebElement> options = selectMonth.findElements(By.tagName("value1"));

for (WebElement option : options) {

if("Alphonso Mango".equals(option.getText()))

option.click();

  METHOD:3

WebElement hiddenWebElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divRawMaterials']/select"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement);
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? What errors do you get for each method?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //div[@id='divRawMaterials']/select

Answer (score 0):

For the drop down to appear you can try the following :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('select[name=\"yieldStandardDTO.rawMaterialName\"]').click();");
```

Now that the drop down is visible, you can use :

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("yieldStandardDTO.rawMaterialName")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("value1");
```